# C# Finding lowest value within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

```
    var minSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Min(x => x.EmpsSalary);
    var empsWithMinSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Where(x => x.EmpsSalary == minSalary);

    string names = "";
    foreach(var e in empsWithMinSalary)
    names += Environment.NewLine + e.EmployeeFirstName;
    string msg = string.Format("The following emplyoees have the lowest salary of {0} : {1}", minSalary, names);
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Above is my code for the find lowest salary button, however where it says "foreach(var e in empsWithMinSalary) i get an error saying e is already in use?

Comment: What have you tried? Add the code which was the closest you could get to achieve what you need.

Comment: that for loop looks a little strange...

Comment: @Magnus I'm assuming it's mean to be 10...

Comment: I don't understand why you create a temporary array of 10 elements if you use just the first one...

Comment: I need to enter up to 10 employees into the array but one at a time because it takes the information from the text boxes on the GUI, so what would be the correct code for creating the array?

Comment: @JackBrown: sorry but it's still unclear to me why do you need a temporary array... just add one item at a time in the listbox... Plus, if that is your real code, `emp` array disappears as soon as the btnSave_Click method exits, so I don't get its purpose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems to me that you're adding text items to the ListBox, so of course it's not easy to get the salary from that.

Instead, you should pass the Employee object to the the listbox to keep all the necessary informations; in this way, your adding method would be :

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var empid = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);
        var empfirstname = Convert.ToString(txtEmployeeFirstName.Text);
        var emplastname = Convert.ToString(txtEmployeeLastName.Text);
        var empsalary = Convert.ToDouble(txtSalary.Text);

        var emp = new Employee(empid, empfirstname, emplastname, empsalary);

        lstEmployeeData.Items.Add(emp);
    }
```

Of course, to get the desired display text you need to re-define `ToString()` method of Employee, for example like this:

```
    class Employee
    {
        // other methods...

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.EmployeeToString();
        }
    }
```

Finally, when the button "show employee having the minimum salary" is clicked you should simply do something like this:

```
private void btnLowestSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var minSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Min(x => x.Salary);
    var empWithMinSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>()
                                          .First(x => x.Salary == minSalary);

    string msg = string.Format("{0} has the lowest salary of {1}", empWithMinSalary.EmployeeFirstName, minSalary);
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

**EDIT :**

In case more than one employee have the same salary you can do something like this:

```
private void btnLowestSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var minSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Min(x => x.Salary);
    var empsWithMinSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>()
                                           .Where(x => x.Salary == minSalary);

    foreach(var e in empsWithMinSalary)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} has the lowest salary of {1}", e.EmployeeFirstName, minSalary);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

Or better:

```
private void btnLowestSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var minSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Min(x => x.Salary);
    var empsWithMinSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>()
                                           .Where(x => x.Salary == minSalary);

    string names = "";
    foreach(var e in empsWithMinSalary)
        names += Environment.NewLine + e.EmployeeFirstName;
    string msg = string.Format("The following emplyoees have the lowest salary of {0} : {1}", minSalary, names);
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Comment: Havin trouble with the show lowest salary, 'x.Salary' is coming up with error the only options are 'x.EmployeeFirstName' and 'x.EmployeeID'.

Comment: @JackBrown: I obviously don't know the name of the property containing the salary, and according to your comment it seems you forgot to expose that. You need to expose a public property in Employee containing the salary and use that instead of x.Salary...

Comment: Okay done that now to display is it just 'MessageBox.Show (minSalary);'?

Comment: I have got it to display and my code so far is: private void btnLowestSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var minSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>().Min(x => x.EmpsSalary);
            var empWithMaxSalary = lstEmployeeData.Items.OfType<Employee>()
                                                  .First(x => x.EmpsSalary == minSalary);

            var result = Convert.ToString(minSalary);
            MessageBox.Show(result);


        }

Comment: How would i get it to say "*employee name* has the lowest salary of *salary here*'

Comment: Thank you so much, one more thing, what about if more than one employee has the same lowest salary.

Comment: Sorry, silly me, all fixed now you have been so much help thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce to you my friend Linq;

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] 
        {
            new Employee { Name = "John", Salary = 9 },
            new Employee { Name = "Paul", Salary = 8 },
            new Employee { Name = "George", Salary = 6 },
            new Employee { Name = "Ringo", Salary = 6 }
        };
        decimal minSalary = emps.Min(x => x.Salary);

        foreach(var e in emps.Where(e => e.Salary == minSalary))
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.Name, e.Salary);
    }
}
```

Live test: http://ideone.com/BYjiW

Comment: didn't see your answer, posted a similar one

Answer (score 0):

This could be done like this:

```
var lowsalemp = from ee in emp where ee.empsalary == (from e in emp select e.empsalary).Min() select ee;
            foreach (var leastsalemp in lowsalemp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(leastsalemp.empsalary);
            }
```

Comment: This will return the minimum salary, not the record